# how to cancel RXJS subscribe after a while

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, observable

If the user's internet is slow and the subscription is taking too long(more than 30 sec), I want to cancel it.

```
const k = this.firebase(user)
        .subscribe(data => {

           //some instructions

        },
        error => alert(error),
        () => console.log("finished"));
}
k.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [Operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) documentation and you will find many interesting things.

Simply use the [Timeout](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html) operator, which is made for specifically this case:

```
const k = this.firebase(user)
    .timeout(30 * 1000)
    .subscribe(
        data => { /* do stuff*/ },
        error => { /* handle it */ },
        () => { /* finished */ }
    );
```

The `timeout` will wait for a value to be emitted up to the time limit, at which point it will end the observable with a failure.

This means that the `error` handler will be called if nothing was received within 30 seconds, and you can use that to notify the user, if you want.

**Update:** Apparently the Firebase client keeps the observable running after receiving a value (presumably so you get notified of further updates). And since the Observable is never completed, Timeout will act after 30 (or whatever you pass as duration) seconds after receiving the data, causing the stream to fail.

To convert the "streaming" Observable into a single-event Observable, use the [Take](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) operator before timing out:

```
this.firebase(user)
    .take(1)
    .timeout(wait)
    .subscribe(/* etc */);
```

Comment: the error alert will always show even if the user got his data after 5 seconds. After the timeout I am getting this error : TimeoutError:Timeout has ocured.

Comment: @user2243952 Ah I see, apparently Firebase keeps its observable open even after receiving (so, of course, you can receive updated data later). Try using `.take(1).timeout(...)` [so that it completes with success after a single event](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html).

Comment: thanks a lot ! but does that mean Firebase observable stops after the first try even thought the timeout is not over yet?

Comment: @user2243952 No, there are no "tries". The observable that `firebase` returns puts out a value every time it changes. The `take` will pass through only a single change, and immediately "finish" the stream. The `timeout` will wait 30s, if the emission happened before that, it will succeed, and if not, will fail. But remember that the stream finishes just after emitting, so the timeout sees that there will be no more data coming in ever and will not error out.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. It was very helpful

Answer (score 6):

You can create another Observable stream using the timer operator and listen to stream k until the timer stream has finished.

ex:

```
const timer$ = Observable.timer(30000) // time in ms
const k$ = this.firebase(user)
    .takeUntil(timer$) // subscribe to k$ until the timer$ finishes
    .subscribe( ... )
```

Comment: I want to show an alert if the time > 30000 . how can I know it the time is exceeded ?

Comment: yeah, @Kroltan answer  ^ is way better for this use case.  Great to know that operator exists! Thanks for upvote though.