# RxJS: How to define a (maximum) duration for an (optional) request?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have this logic:

```
  public setXXXInLocalStorage(): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.appConfig.getEndpoint('xxx')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((endpoint: Endpoint) => this.http.get(endpoint.toUrl(), {headers})),
        map((body: any) => { localStorage.setItem('myItem', body.item); }),
        timeout(5000),
        map(() => true),
        catchError(() => of(true))
      );
  }
```

What i wanted to achieve is, that i want to wait for max. 5 seconds for my get request.

- switchmap: calls my endpoint
- map: deals with the answer
- timeout: i tried to define max. 5 sec. for this call
- map: if success, we should do nothing but just return true
- catchError: if any error occurs from the request, or timeout occurs, we can also simply ignore the error and simply return true

What is now happening is: timeout waits always 5 seconds, even when my get request returns success in 1 sec.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `switchMap((endpoint: Endpoint) => this.http.get(endpoint.toUrl(), {headers})).pipe(timeout(5000))` if you want to wait for this call. And your `map(() => true)` will replace the value of you stream to `true` - it will never emit anything else than `true`

Comment: that's ok, i just want to emit true outside. in success i just set sth. in localstorage

Comment: btw. with your suggestion: ERROR TypeError: Object(...)(...).pipe is not a function

Comment: Yes, remove one last round bracket from `{headers})).pipe`

Answer (score 2):

i think this solved my problem: [how to cancel RXJS subscribe after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001057/how-to-cancel-rxjs-subscribe-after-a-while)

From @Kroltan:

> Apparently rxjs client keeps the observable running
>   after receiving a value (presumably so you get notified of further
>   updates). And since the Observable is never completed, Timeout will
>   act after 30 (or whatever you pass as duration) seconds after
>   receiving the data, causing the stream to fail.
>
> To convert the "streaming" Observable into a single-event Observable,
>   use the Take operator before timing out:

So i just needed to add a take(1) before my timeout.

```
public setXXXInLocalStorage(): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.appConfig.getEndpoint('xxx')
      .pipe(
        switchMap((endpoint: Endpoint) => this.http.get(endpoint.toUrl(), {headers})),
        tap((body: any) => { localStorage.setItem('myItem', body.item); }),
        take(1),
        timeout(5000),
        map(() => true),
        catchError(() => of(true))
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `timeout` operator follows the `map` operator, the value returned from the callback to the `map` operator is important as it determines what value is passed to the `timeout` logic. Since there is no return value in your `map` operation, then the `timeout` operator is passed `undefined` when it evaluates the Observable emission from the source (the HTTP `get`).

Since an Observable of `undefined` never completes, then the `timeout` operator will throw an error always (after the time specified).

Instead of using `map` for the side-effect of setting a value in local storage, use [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) which will just ferry the source observable on to the next operator in the pipe.

```js
const endpoint = rxjs.of('blah');

function getRequest(httpObservable, name) {
  return endpoint.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.switchMap(() => httpObservable),
    rxjs.operators.tap((val) => { // Call `tap` instead of `map`
      console.log(`${name}: ${val}`);
    }),
    rxjs.operators.timeout(2000),
    rxjs.operators.map(() => true),
  ).subscribe(
    null,
    () => console.log(`${name} Errored!`),
    () => console.log(`${name} Complete!`)
  );
}

const http = rxjs.timer(500);
const slowHttp = rxjs.timer(4000);

getRequest(http, 'Quick HTTP');
getRequest(slowHttp, 'Slow HTTP');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.5.2/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: this change unfortunately did not bring any improvement :/  the problem is actually i see your console logs (in my case my success result) immediately, but my protractor tests wait always for this timeout... so there is like a thread from timeout, which runs besides and ends only in timeout duration (2000s in your case), even in success case.

Comment: i think we do not have the logic in this code, which intercepts timeout in success case.. our timeout promise runs always, even if our request returns success.. i actually want that it only runs while waiting for the response, not after the response is there..